# Can, or not, a compiled for Linux program access her own memory without getting any access violation?

Tags: c++, c, linux

**Introduction**. (skip to the question please ;)

There was a time when a program can do the things in a way I like her to do them. Some time passed, I have found that I can't do some of them any more.
I hope there is a way still, though..

Maybe there are options in compiler, maybe in loader, maybe in kernel (I'm interested in Linux OS, newbie in it, though), have no idea where; but sorry - I don't want to end up as dead while searching..

**The question**.

I want to run a code in a program that has been modified by that program (producing assembler instructions). Tried it - got the SIGSEGV as result of changing the immediate data in the code segment. I need a way to make the code segment writable etc, ONLY for my own USER-space program. Where to start?

Thanks.

P.S. As suggested tags were c++/linux/c, added them.

Comment: Use a bare-metal embedded system. There are very good reasons for protected memory systems.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Read about the `mprotect` systemcall.

Comment: What you're asking about is commonly called "self-modifying code".

Comment: Self-modifying code is an abomination anyway.  It's not thread-safe, for starters.

Comment: to FUZxxl: thanks, will read.